# Setting Interval For Activiry and Perform Task

Tags: android

Is there any function in Android that can use to make the activity wait for an interval and continue working?

I mean , for example, I use `setContentView()` to set a layout , and after 3 seconds it will load another layout, and continue to do another job, I don't need to repeat doing same thing after an interval, just continue do another thing.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @XaverKapeller "You can call setContentView() only once" that's incorrect. It usually isn't a good idea to call it multiple times in one `Activity` but you certainly can

Comment: @xtiger, please tell me this isn't for a splash screen...

Comment: @XaverKapeller you can call setContentView multiple times,  but of course it not the way it should be done

Comment: I think use `AlarmManager` and `Broadcast` is more accurate, though it's more complex.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Why do you say that? [INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Use Following Method to Set Interval

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Do your code here

        }
    }, 3000);
```

Here, 1000 = 1 Second

But Before running this code make sure that you are not in BACKGROUND PROCESS THREAD...otherwise this may cause an error..

Comment: make sure you are on the UI Thread if you use this.. Otherwise call Handler mHandler = new Handler(); before using postDelayed on a Background Thread. You will get an exception otherwise.

Comment: if you are in backgrouund thread you should properly use runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {})

Comment: That will also work. But its important not to instantiate a Handler on a background thread is all i am saying.

Answer (score 1):

Do it at Android Style:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(runnableHandler, 3000);

private Runnable runnableHandler = new Runnable() {
      @Override
    public void run() {
    doSomething()
  }
};

private void doSomething() {
  // Before do something remove all callbacks from Handler
  mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnableHandler);

  andFinallyDoWhatYouNeed();
}
```

Comment: You don't need this line here: `mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnableHandler);`. And doing this is generally unadvisable unless for very specific reasons.

Comment: This line (removeCallbacks) is for safe, in case more then one time a runnable is enqueued. Just for stay safer! BTW if you are reseanable sure to enqueue handler runnable quitely, remove the line

Comment: Yes I understand what `removeCallbacks()` does, but you are creating a new `Handler`. There are and could never be other `Runnables` since you only post one. And doing this when you are using a `Handler` from somewhere else can mess alot of things up. It can cancel all sorts of `Animations`, `FragmentTransactions` and everything else which uses `Handlers` (which is pretty much everything). So you see, it is pointless in your case and can cause a whole slew of problems if you use an already existing `Handler`. Methods like this should only called if you have a very good reason.

Comment: Is to inform the developer to stay safer... I posted a summary snapshot of code, not an enterily solution, so I don't know how many times he wants to call the postdelay; You are right in your explanation, but my code is for generally usage of 'mHandler.postDelay()'. However, the 'removeCallbacks()' are related only to 'the mHandler' mentioned for the example. **BTW Many thanks for your clarification**